# How to disable attach file email in magento 1.x

Tags: magento2, email

i want disable attach file email, after checkout, there will be email sent to customers, and attached pdf invoice file. Is there any way to turn it off? Please help me how to find it, i can't find it

Answer (score 2):

this might be happening by any custom third-party extension or customization because this is not a default Magento functionality to attach pdf with email.

Comment: i know, but i don't know edit it, i need a key search, ex: addAttachment. i tryed it but after edit, nothing changes

Comment: have you disabled that extension and try?